# Run Batch Process with Oauth2.0_token

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, batch-processing, httr

I am trying to connect to the Instagram API using R and want my code to run as  a batch process on an Ubuntu server.  Currently, I am using `oauth2.0_token` and running into an error when it needs to connect to the browser for authentication.

When I try to connect to the API on the server, I get this message

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

What would be a way to get around this? Or is there a better way to connect to the Instagram API?

Here is an example of the code I am currently using that is producing the error

```
app_name <- 'Testing'
client_id <- 'XXXXXXX'
client_secret <- 'XXXXXXX'
scope = 'basic'

instagram <- oauth_endpoint(
authorize = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
access = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token")
myapp <- oauth_app(app_name, client_id, client_secret)

ig_oauth <- ?oauth2.0_token(instagram, myapp,scope="basic",  
                       type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",cache=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your code that produces this message.

Comment: Hmm, if you are logging in via shell to a remote server, I imagine that won't work as it would need you an interactive component, right @Thomas ?  Do they support a personal access token authentication scheme? If so, you could pass that in the request

Comment: Either cache, or use out-of-band (oob) auth.